# Format result from a batch file ping command

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ping

I wrote a bat file that takes the IP addresses of all of our stores and pings them. I would like to format the results so that it would return only the time response.

Currently I am using something like:
`ping -n 1  xx.xxx.xxx.xx   | FIND "TTL=" >>output.txt`

This gives me only one echo request response, which is what I want. I just want to get rid of the bolded text.
**Reply from xx.xxx.xxx.xx: bytes=32 time=** 22ms **TTL=57**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the result through a `for` loop and use spaces and `=` signs as delimiters to extract only the time.

```
for /F "tokens=7 delims==< " %%A in ('ping -n 1 xx.xxx.xxx.xx ^| find "TTL"') do (
    echo %%A>>output.txt
)
```

Comment: Might fail as e.g. `ping -4 localhost` returns `time<1ms`. In fact, I can't simulate extreme slow response; who knows output in that case? I'd use `for /F "tokens=5"` and then remove the `time` word

Comment: I've added `<` as a delimiter, and as long as the ping doesn't timeout (e.g. `ping 1.1.1.1`), it should work out.

Comment: You could add a "-w 200" to the ping options to shorten the delay in case the host is unreachable. To make it work with multiple hosts, wrap it in a for-loop over all args: `for %%H in (%*) do (for /F ... ping %%H ...)`

Comment: @wilb - sure thing. If my solution worked for you, please click the check mark next to my answer.